# 'There are no images open', ImageJ, python3

Tags: python-3.x, headless, imagej

I am encountering an annoying issue when I run the code below I am given 'There are no images open'.

I use the following python script to run an imageJ macro:

```
IJ.open(fin_fus)
IJ.saveAs("tiff", sav_dir_fu)
IJ.runMacroFile(lord_s_path + "\Macro_All_.ijm", str(ch_no))
IJ.saveAs("tiff", sav_dir_pro)
print("Processing successful")
```

I run the macro (below, not in full for simplification) in headless mode, and "Fn", "ch_no" and "processing composite" are all printed, so I presume that the image has been found but whenever I run this I get "There are no images open" as an error. Does anyone know how to fix this? There are similar questions on here but none had an answer which solved my troubles so sorry in advance if this is a potential repeat.

```
Fn = getTitle()
print(Fn)
ch_no = getArgument()
print(ch_no)
if (is("composite")){
print("processing composite");
//run("Channels Tool...");
Stack.setDisplayMode("color");
Stack.setChannel(1);
run("Red");
Stack.setChannel(2);
run("Green");
Stack.setChannel(3);
run("Magenta");
Stack.setChannel(4);
run("Cyan");
Stack.setChannel(1);
run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
Stack.setChannel(2);
run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
Stack.setChannel(3);
run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
Stack.setChannel(4);
run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
run("Rotate 90 Degrees Right");
run("Properties...", "unit=um pixel_width=0.3250000 pixel_height=0.3250000 voxel_depth=3.4000000");
```

Comment: From the description of the #imagej tag: Please consider asking ImageJ-specific questions on the Image.sc forum: https://forum.image.sc/tags/imagej

Comment: Thanks. It's posted on there now.